# Custom UICollectionViewCell not showing changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have created class that extends `UICollectionViewCell` and cell was customised within the storyboard. Within the `initWithCoder` for the cell I modify the labels shadow.

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        self.artistNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:12];
        self.artistNameLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.artistNameLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.65];
        self.artistNameLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        self.artistNameLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
        self.artistNameLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
        return self;
    }
```

For some reasons the changes do not show up, even though the init is called when creating the cell.

If I move the shadow code into `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` it shows fine, but obviously this is not very good for reuse.

Comment: Why is doing it in cellForItem... not good for reuse?

Comment: Oh.  I think I understand what you mean. Reuse between different collection views.  @JohnErck has a good idea.

Comment: I actually meant for reuse within the individual cells. I thought that by applying the shadow inside cellForItem... it would add the shadow to label each time a cell is created. Rather than adding the shadow once, and then just editing the text when reusing the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move it over to `- (void)awakeFromNib`. That's a much better place to put it.

Answer (score 2):

Make a single public method on your custom cell called something like `updateUI` and call that from within your `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. You can alloc init your collection view cell's var's in your `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method, but to have your shadowRadius, shadowOpacity, etc go into effect I recommend the approach described above.

```
#pragma mark - Helpers

- (void)updateUI // Update data within alreay alloc inited UI elements
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.myImageView.frame = self.contentView.frame;
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}

- (void)setup // Alloc init UI elements
{
    self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.myImageView];
}

#pragma mark - Lifecycle Methods

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wouldn't this approach mean that the shadow layer is set each time a cell is drawn, instead of drawing it once and then just editing the text on future labels?

Comment: This means the shadow layer is set each time the cell is about to come on screen. The shadow is drawn every time the cell moves which is different than setting a property and something you don't interface with. The alloc init happens only once for each subview in your view at time of initialization and not at time of `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

For answer on your i need little bit more information but check next

1) Are you using your custom UICollectionViewCell

[image]

2) In method

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   DomyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DomyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```